# как на Python правильно сделать Parsing сайта и убрать две строки?

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4, parse

```
course = requests.get(config.minfit_site).text
b = bs4.BeautifulSoup(course, "html.parser")

pln_0 = b.find('div', class_='mfm-grey-bg').select('span', class_='mfm-posr')[0].text
pln_1 = b.find('div', class_='mfm-grey-bg').select('span', class_='mfm-posr')[2].text

print(pln_0, pln_1)
```

Результат
7.8000
**-0.100** забрать
8.2200
**-0.030** забрать

Comment: А какой сайт? Мало инфы чтобы что-то советовать

Comment: https://minfin.com.ua/ua/currency/pln/ - єтот сайт хотел пропасить для валют

Comment: там тег <span> удаетса пропасить, но сразу за ним следущий идет... и не могу понять как его не  тронуть

Comment: Вы можете нормально вопрос задать?

Comment: Результат 7.8000 -0.100 забрать 8.2200 -0.030 забрать
как убрать 2 и 4 числа!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ну примерно так:

```
z = b.find('div', class_='mfm-grey-bg').select('span', class_='mfm-posr')
pln_0, _ = z[0].stripped_strings
pln_1, _ = z[2].stripped_strings

print(pln_0, pln_1)

# 7.8000 8.2200

pf0 = float(pln_0)
print(pf0, type(pf0))

# 7.8 <class 'float'>
```

Comment: просто в точку, спасиба!
и последний вопрос , я могу переобразить етот текст в float?

Comment: str(float(pln_0)) не сильно помагает

Comment: М да, проблема, у гугла не пробывали спросить?

Comment: к сожалению сам пробивал. но хочу узнать как, бо учусь и небила своево наставника. тому прошу прощения за тупасть которую могу пред'явить совсем банально.

Comment: в ответ загляните

Comment: если уже так, то бот впринимает float опать как str . и попросту передать значение "pf0" не получаетса - Expected type 'str', got 'float' instead

Answer (score 0):

решение было таким:

```
str(float(pf0*summ))
```

вместо:

```
str(float(pf0))*summ
```